# SQLite foreign key mismatch when trying to insert null value

Tags: sqlite, foreign-keys

I have the following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE "Abilities" (
"ID"    INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
"Name"  TEXT NOT NULL,
"Description"   TEXT NOT NULL
)
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE "Creatures" (
"ID"    INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
"Faction"   TEXT,
"Name"  TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
"Tier"  INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
"Upgrade"   INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
"GoldCost"  INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
"PopulationWeekly"  INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
"Attack"    INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
"Defense"   INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
"DamageMin" INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
"DamageMax" INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
"Initiative"    INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
"Speed" INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
"Health"    INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
"Mana"  INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
"Shots" INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
"Experience"    INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
"PowerRating"   INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
"Abilities" TEXT,
FOREIGN KEY("Abilities") REFERENCES "Abilities"("Name")
)
```

When trying to do the following insert:

```
INSERT INTO "main"."Creatures"
("Faction", "Name", "Abilities")
VALUES ('Academy', 'Gremlin', null);
```

I get a:

```
Result: foreign key mismatch - "Creatures" referencing "Abilities"
At line 1:
INSERT INTO "main"."Creatures"
("Faction", "Name", "Abilities")
VALUES ('Academy', 'Gremlin', null);
```

error. But I thought it would be OK if I try to insert a 'null' into a foreign key? In this case I want to be able to insert empty values for some "Ability" values, since not all records must have an "Ability" value.

How do I make it so that whenever something is inserted into "Creatures" SQL would check if "Ability" IS NOT NULL then the record must exist in the "Name" column of the "Abilities" table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the referenced column `Name` in the table `Abilities` is not the `PRIMARY KEY` of the table (why do you want the name in `Creatures` and not the `id` which is the usual practice?) and it is not either `UNIQUE`.
 
If the referenced column is not `UNIQUE` you can't insert any value in the column `Abilities` of the table `Creatures` and not only `NULL`.
 
Change to this:

```
CREATE TABLE "Abilities" (
    "ID"    INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
    "Name"  TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    "Description"   TEXT NOT NULL
)
```

Now you will be able to insert NULL values in the column `Abilities` of the table `Creatures`.
But the best thing to do is to have an integer column like `Abilities_Id` in `Creatures`, referencing the `PRIMARY KEY` of the table `Abilities` instead of `Name`.
You can find more here: [SQLite Foreign Key Support](https://sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html)

Comment: Ah, thanks! My logic was that I wanted to have the column "Ability" in "Creatures" be the names of the abilities a certain creature has, it didn't occur to me it would be better to be an integer field tied to the ID in "Abilities". Just to verify - technically, I COULD reference "Name" and it would work, as long as it is marked as "Unique"? Of course, I'm not going to do that, now, but I'm just curious. :)